# Separating functionality out into separate index.js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, module, singleton

I'm collaborating on a new NodeJS module with a colleague and the file structure is as follows:

**index.js**

```
let MyModule = require('./src/index.js);

MyModule = new MyModule();

module.exports = MyModule;
```

**src/index.js**

```
const depA = require('depA');

const MyModule = function MyModule() {
  this.doStuff = function doStuff() {
    console.log('doing stuff...)
  }
}

module.exports = MyModule;
```

I'm wondering if there is any need/value to split into these two index.js files and whether it would be better to have just one top level file. Is this considered an anti-pattern? I did wonder if this approach works better when you have a complex library with functionality split out across many feature files.

Comment: On a sidenote, you should rather write `myModule = new MyModule(); module.exports = myModule;`: capitalized variable names are for object creators and interfaces, and `myModule` is an instance.

Comment: Definitely should be separated, imo. If the consumer wants access to the class rather than a singleton instance, they can still include the `./src` directly, so the singleton pattern should not be tightly coupled with the implementation.